# Problem related to building a network between cassandra nodes via docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, cassandra

I am a trainee and for work I created a Docker Compose script to deploy a cluster of three cassandra instances, each of them is accessible from the main (local) network by a separate ip address. Initially I used the default parameter for the container network, but as it turned out I needed all containers (raised on pc 1) to be accessible to pc 2, which is on the same network as the first one. In order to refine my network I used the driver macvlan settings, but this solution did not help, I still can't build a connection for the containers on the other pc in any way